# C# Silverlight 3 - Programmatically Navigate Between Pages?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, navigation

Say I have a C# Silverlight 3 application with a number of pages. The first page is called Home, and the second page is called Details. The only way to navigate to details is programmatically. How do I do this?! Looked everywhere for the answer and all i've found are xaml uri mapper implementations....

Help greatly appreciated

Comment: Which version of Silverlight?

Comment: Silverlight 3...........

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the NavigationService?

this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Details.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Comment: In Silverlight URI reverenses are relative to the XAP. The Uri for the detailspage (if it's in the root of your project) should be 'new Uri("/Details.xaml", UriKind.Relative)

Comment: I'm telling you 100% this does not work. Brand new Silverlight Business Application Template, Trying to navigate to literally any page doesn't work using that method.

Comment: Are you trying to navigation from ur ViewModel in a MVVM app, or from the xaml.cs?

Answer (score 7):

c#:

```
this.navContent.Navigate(new Uri("Welcome", UriKind.Relative));
```

XAML:

```
<navigation:Frame
    x:Name="navContent"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    Source="Welcome">
    <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
        <uriMapper:UriMapper>
            <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="Welcome" MappedUri="/Views/Welcome.xaml" />
            <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="Profile" MappedUri="/Views/Profile.xaml" />
            <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="Details/{id}" MappedUri="/Views/Details.xaml?photoid={id}" />
        </uriMapper:UriMapper>
    </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
</navigation:Frame>
```

Even your "details" page should be mapped (despite what you said.)

Answer (score 7):

C#
App.Current.Host.NavigationState = "/Welcome";

XAML

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is:

Add this code to your App.xaml.cs:

```
private static Grid root;

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    root = new Grid();
    root.Children.Add(new MainPage());

    this.RootVisual = root;
}

public static void Navigate(UserControl newPage)
{
    UserControl oldPage = root.Children[0] as UserControl;

    root.Children.Add(newPage);
    root.Children.Remove(oldPage);
}
```

And then, to navigate between pages, you'll just have to call:

```
App.Navigate(new OtherSamplePage());
```

Comment: I've been searching everywhere for this answer +3 if I could

Answer (score 2):

Try using this. This worked for me.

((System.Windows.Controls.Frame)(this.Parent)).Navigate(new Uri("/Import",UriKind.Relative));