# how to navigate on the button click

Tags: silverlight

I am developing a SilverLight Project using **SilverLight BusinessApplication** Template RIA services.I want to navigate from one xaml page to another xaml page on the click of a Button that is placed on the first Xaml Page. i don't want to use Hyperlink button.

Any Suggestions...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Silverlight 3 - Programmatically Navigate Between Pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498071/c-silverlight-3-programmatically-navigate-between-pages)

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498071/c-silverlight-3-programmatically-navigate-between-pages):

Put this inside the event handler of the button:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("nextpage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```